# If the client accepts the plugin, can I know his navigation?

Tags: php, asp.net, ajax, cross-browser

I'm trying to make a page divided in 2 frames. One that shows an external page... a shop for example,and other(mine) that offers related content to what is being shown in the external page.

I've been searching how to know the URL of the frame, but it can't be done due to security reasons(XSS, clickjacking, etc). 
But I know it has to be one way to know it. I recently read that some plugins like the facebook's, have the ability to know where the client is while he is navigating.

I hope that my intention is clear. Do you know if this is possible?

Answer (score 0):

Without having the site's owner install some JS on their site, you will find it very hard to find a cross-browser way to do this. FB do have people include a script and this is how they are able to access information cross domain.

You may be able to create plugins to do this, however you will have to create one per browser.

Comment: Ok, I think that is not going to be posible in the beggining . Maybe I should make a catalog in my own site instead.